# c# index outside the bounds of the array, never breaks out of the for-loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

My program compiles but when runnng it never breaks out of the loop and says the array is too big.  This is my code:

```
public class ComparableArray
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
    taxpayer[] taxArray = new taxpayer[5];
    int x;
    for(x= 0; x < taxArray.Length; ++x)
        taxArray[x] = new taxpayer();

        Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
        taxArray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter gross income for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
                    taxArray[x].Income = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        taxpayer.getRates();
        x++;

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe it's the annual homework assigned by the government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers were incorrect, thanks for the help though. I was using x twice; once in the for loop and also in the Console.Write, I just changed the for loop to y instead and works great.

```
int x=0;
int y;
for(y= 0; y < taxArray.Length; ++y){
    taxArray[x] = new taxpayer();

    Console.Write("Enter Social Security Number for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
    taxArray[x].SSN = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter gross income for taxpayer {0}: ", x+1);
    taxArray[x].Income = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    taxpayer.getRates();
    x++;
}
```

Comment: The point of the other answers was that you didn't need to have x++ in the body of your for loop at all. Now you added a `y` variable that would be unnecessary if you followed the suggestions in the other posts.

Comment: I have x+1 to keep track of the taxpayer number. that is why I was getting the error. I Tried the suggestions from the other posts and I still got the same error message. Changing it to y fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You are incrementing x twice in your loop:

Once here:

```
for(x= 0; x < taxArray.Length; ++x)
```

and once here:

```
x++;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to increment the loop counter `x++;` in the body of the loop. The loop already does that.

Answer (score 2):

The [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop should be declared a bit differently:

```
// notice the inclusion of the variable type in the for
// and you want to use x++, not ++x
for(int x= 0; x < taxArray.Length; x++)
```

But, the real problem is the incrementing of `x++` inside the loop. Since the `for` loop declaration includes an incrementer (x++), there's no need to increment inside the loop as well.